# Multiple instances of the same Property in one Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

This is my model code:

```
public class Dog
{
    [Key]
    public int DogID { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "Namn")]
    public string DogName { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public int KennelID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("KennelID")]
    public virtual Kennel Kennel { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public int RaceID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RaceID")]
    public virtual Race Race1 { get; set; }

    public int RaceID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RaceID")]
    public virtual Race Race2 { get; set; }

    public int RaceID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RaceID")]
    public virtual Race Race3 { get; set; }

    public int RaceID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RaceID")]
    public virtual Race Race4 { get; set; }
```

Error messages:

```
Models.Dog' already contains a definition for 'RaceID'
Models.Dog' already contains a definition for 'RaceID'
Models.Dog' already contains a definition for 'RaceID'
```

I don't understand why MVC will not let me do this to begin with! Why can't a Model have multiple Properties (`Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4`) That is selected from the `RaceID` ForeignKey property in the `Race` Model?

This is really annoying me. I looked at some search results about this error but I did not understand them.

So the question: **How will I get multiple instances of one property to a Model?** I read about a AllowMultiple snippet in the controller, but I need to understand what I am building.

Are there any guides that can make me understand Model relationships better?
I'd prefer guides that are video or step-by-step style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple class members with the same name (in your case RaceID).

Change to:

```
public int Race2ID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Race2ID")]
public virtual Race Race2 { get; set; }
```

and so on. `Race2ID` will be the id of the second race.

Comment: I can't seem to get this Model to work. New Error then is too many `ForeignKeys`


Errorcode: `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Dogs_dbo.Races_Race2ID' on table 'Dogs' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint.`



What is wrong with my Model relationships?

Comment: @JuliusHolmberg Show me your Race class